# Assume $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $x=a$. Prove $h=\max\{f,g\}$ is continuous at $x=a$.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, continuity

Assume $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $x=a$. Prove $h=\max\{f,g\}$ is continuous at $x=a$.

My solution:

When $f\ge g\Rightarrow h=\max\{f,g\}=f$ and since $f$ is continuous at $x=a$ so is $h$.

When $f<g\Rightarrow h=\max\{f,g\}=g$ and since $g$ is continuous at $x=a$ so is $h$.

Does this seem sufficient?

Comment: Note that you don't cover all cases, there are functions that neither $f \geq g$ nor $f < g$ near $x = a$. A standard argument is using the fact that for all real numbers $a, b$ the following holds $$\max(a,b) = \frac{a + b + | a + b|}{2}$$

Comment: @Azlif Firstly, thank you for your answer! However, I don't seem to understand what other functions does the $h$ put out when $f\ge g$ nor $f<g$?

Comment: for example $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = -x$ on the right of zero,  you have $f(x) > g(x)$ but  on the left $f(x) < g(x)$. i.e., you can't say that $f\geq g$ nor $f < g$ in some neighborhood of zero.

Comment: Consider three cases, $f(a)>g(a), f(a)=g(a), f(a) < g(a)$. It is easy to see that the $\max$ is continuous at the first and third of these cases, so the only one that needs attention is the middle one.

Comment: @copper.hat that doesn't cover all cases too

Comment: @Azlif: It does. I'm curious what other possibilities you envision? We are dealing with reals here.

Comment: @copper.hat note that in any neighborhood of zero, like an example I gave, neither $f(x) > g(x)$ nor $g(x) > f(x) $ nor $f(x) = g(x)$ $for~all$ $x$ in these neighborhood.

Comment: @Azlif: I said nothing about all $x$. My comment does not contain the letter $x$. I know what you are trying to say, but that is not the content of my comment.

Answer (score 4):

No, not at all. By the same argument, if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable, then so is $\max\{f,g\}$. However, $\max\{x,-x\}=\lvert x\rvert$.

Comment: Doesn't differentiability require _more_ than continuity?  A continuous function need not be differentiable.

Comment: Of course! I am just asserting that *the same argument* applies to differentiability.

Answer (score 0):

We always have $x_k \le y_k + |x_k - y_k| \le y_k +\|x-y\|_\infty$.

Hence $x_k \le \max_j y_j +\|x-y\|_\infty$ and so $\max_j x_k \le \max_j y_j +\|x-y\|_\infty$.

Reversing the roles of $x,y$ gives $|\max_k x_k - \max_k y_k| \le \|x-y\|_\infty$.

In particular, the $\max$ is Lipschitz with rank one.

Now consider the function $x \mapsto \max(f(x),g(x))$.

**Alternative**:

Suppose $f(a) > g(a)$. Then there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ such that $f(x)>g(x)$
for $x\in U$. Hence $\max(f(x),g(x)) = f(x)$ for $x \in U$ and so $h$ is continuous.

The case $f(a) < g(a)$ is similar.

If $f(a) = g(a)$, let $\epsilon>0$ and choose a neighbourhood $U$ such that
$|f(x)-f(a)| < \epsilon$ and $|g(x)-g(a)| < \epsilon$ for $x \in U$.
Then
$-\epsilon+f(a) < f(x) < f(a) + \epsilon$ and $-\epsilon+f(a) < g(x) < f(a) + \epsilon$ for $x \in U$ and
so $-\epsilon+f(a) <\max(f(x),g(x)) < f(a) + \epsilon$ for $x \in U$.
Hence $| h(x)-h(a) | < \epsilon$.

Comment: Very nice. Does this argument work for arbitrary index sets, assuming that the $\max$ is always well-defined?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist: If you replace $\max$ by $\sup$, yes.

Comment: Could anyone shed some light on the two downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

At $x=a$, use the fact that

$$\max{(f,g)}=\frac{1}{2}(f+g+|f-g|).$$

Comment: Thank you for answering! However, I don't think I have come across that expression yet. Where is it derived from?

Comment: @Joe This is true for real numbers .It follows directly from the definition of the maximum function